# OOP in Corona, accessing vars from outside class

Tags: oop, lua, coronasdk

looking for some help with accessing variables from outside a Corona OOP class.  Here's the bare-bones code:

```
module(..., package.seeall)

local widget = require "widget"

picker = {}
picker.__index = picker

function picker.new()
local picker_object = {}
setmetatable(picker_object,picker)

picker_object.theHour = 12
picker_object.theMin = 0
picker_object.am = true

return picker_object
end

function picker:getHour()
return self.theHour
end

function picker:getMin()
return self.theMin
end
```

self is coming back as nil when I try and call getHour and getMin from outside the class.  What syntax should I use instead to return my theHour and theMin variables?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and there's nothing wrong with it. The problem is probably in the way you're accessing this module. Here's my main.lua that works with your code (I gonna guess your file is named picker.lua):

```
local picker = require "picker"
local picker_obj = picker.picker.new() 
                -- the first picker is the module (picker.lua)
                       -- the second is the picker class in the file
print("minute: " .. picker_obj:getMin())
print("hour: " .. picker_obj:getHour())
```

Also, The module(..., package.seeall) command has been deprecated, see [this blog post for a better way to make your module.](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/09/05/a-better-approach-to-external-modules/) If you use this method to create your module and still call your file picker.lua, the first two lines in my main.lua would change to:

```
local picker = require "picker"
local picker_obj = picker.new()
```

Here's the simplest way I would modify your code to use the new way of creating modules. Only the beginning and end change, everything else stays the same:

```
-- got rid of module(), made picker local
local picker = {}
picker.__index = picker

... -- all the functions stay the same

return picker
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer brando!  Interesting.  Argh deprecation!  I just updated to a newer release of Corona and have spent half an hour going through my app, taking out the widget .view stuff and fixing similar bugs!  I am a little unclear how I change my class to fit in with the new method - do i not need picker.__index = picker any more?  what about picker_object?  I juuuuust got it all working and I am so scared I'm going to break it! :)

Comment: For OOP, you still need picker.__index = picker and picker_object. I updated the answer to show how use the new method for modules. You could change your functions to be more like the blog post describes, but you don't have to. What you have will work, just make sure any private functions you add are local and not class members, so: local function foo()